# What do people call functionals on holomorphic functions and on polynomials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry

There are four most important functional spaces in analysis:

- the space $\mathcal{C}(M)$ of continuous functions on a topological space,
- the space $\mathcal{E}(M)$ of smooth functions on a smooth manifold,
- the space $\mathcal{O}(M)$ of holomorphic functions on a complex manifold, and
- the space $\mathcal{P}(M)$ of polynomials on an algebraic manifold.

In the first two cases the functionals on the  spaces have well-known names:

- continuous functionals $f:\mathcal{C}(M)\to\mathbb{C}$ are called *measures*, and
- continuous functionals $f:\mathcal{E}(M)\to\mathbb{C}$ are called *distributions*.

> What do people call continuous functionals on $\mathcal{O}(M)$ and on $\mathcal{P}(M)$?

(The space $\mathcal{O}(M)$ is endowed with the usual compact-open topology, and the space $\mathcal{P}(M)$ with the strongest locally convex topology, so each linear functional on $\mathcal{P}(M)$ is continuous.)

I saw the names *analytic functionals* for $f:\mathcal{O}(M)\to\mathbb{C}$, and *currents* for $f:\mathcal{P}(M)\to\mathbb{C}$, but both terms sound strange to me.

Is it possible that there are more or less convenient names for these objects?

Comment: In p-adic functional analysis it's conventional that the dual of the space of "[whatever] functions" gets called the space of "[whatever] distributions" (with measures being the exception to this convention). Not sure if this is a general convention though. I'd certainly use "algebraic distributions" for the dual of your $\mathcal{P}(M)$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler yes, this sounds logical, but, to tell the truth, the terms "algebraic distribution", "holomorphic distribution", "smooth distribution", "continuous distribution" are strange as well... "Holomorphic distribution" does not seem to be holomorphic in any reasonable sense. Similarly, "algebraic distribution", etc.

Comment: "Analytic functionals" is a standard name. See, Hormander, The analysis of linear partial differential operators I, Chap. 9.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko thank you. And what is the term for functionals on $\mathcal{P}(M)$?

Comment: This I do not know.

Comment: Actually, I don't like the name "analytic functional", because it's impossible to explain in which sense it is analytic. This is like "smooth functional" for $f:\mathcal{E}(M)\to\mathbb{C}$. Such functionals, i.e. distributions, usually are not smooth. I expected there are better terms.